# running run-app: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager'

Tags: grails

When I run my Grails application in STS I am getting the following error.
Before that I was trying different

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5"
```

I was changing from 2.5 to 3.0 and then changing back from 3.0 to 2.5 again.

This happens when I run my app from STS:

```
|Loading Grails 2.3.5
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
.........................................................................................................2015-05-13 08:28:41,492 [main] INFO  conf.Config  - catalinaBase: D:\tomcat7
2015-05-13 08:28:41,492 [main] INFO  conf.Config  - catalinaBase: D:\tomcat7
..
|Running Grails application
|Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/
2015-05-13 08:29:04,495 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  conf.Config  - catalinaBase: D:\tomcat7
2015-05-13 08:29:15,977 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError
    ... 5 more
2015-05-13 08:29:15,979 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError
    ... 5 more
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to let you know. I found the issue:

I was incorrectly defining a property in my Domain Class which led to the error.

By reading the error I was NOT thinking of an error in my Domain Class definition.

That was the problematic line in my Domain Class.

```
static hasMany = [ attachments: long ]
```